# Delete captured image in imageCapture of QML Camera

Tags: qt, qml

I'm working on a image processing application and I use this code

```
Camera {
    id: cam
    viewfinder.resolution: "640x480"
    viewfinder.minimumFrameRate: 5
    captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage
    imageCapture {
        resolution: "640x480"
        onReadyChanged: {
            imageDecoder.reset()  // my decoder class
            cam.imageCapture.capture()
        }
        onImageCaptured: {
            console.log(requestId, preview)
            imageDecoder.decodeQmlPreview(preview)
        }
    }
    imageProcessing {
        contrast: 0.60
    }
}


VideoOutput {
    id: output
    fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: cam        
}
```

I see that all these captured images (`preview`) are stored on the hard drive and are never being deleted. How to delete these images? I have very limited hard disk space available.

```
# ls -lh | grep IMG
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       10.5K Jan  1 00:40 IMG_00000001.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       12.2K Jan  1 00:45 IMG_00000002.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       15.6K Jan  1 00:48 IMG_00000003.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       15.6K Jan  1 00:49 IMG_00000004.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       11.4K Jan  1 01:05 IMG_00000005.jpg
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that these are coming from your qml? How have you isolated that?\

Comment: @KubaOber they do match the video output display. I deleted all those files and reran the application as well. The file count matches my processed image count.

Comment: I'd consider it a Qt bug, then, as long as the code you show is complete. If so, file a bug report.

Comment: Not that it will do much good. The right course would be to focus on finding a workaround, until the bug gets fixed, which may take years.

Answer (score 1):

QML has a rather implicit relation to the FS - its internal functionality will read and sometimes write, but it doesn't seem to have a defined API for the user to interact directly with the FS.

Which means you will have to implement that functionality in C++, and expose it to QML.

My practice is to create a `class System : public QObject` and put all the necessary stuff inside, and then in `main.cpp`:

```
  System s(&engine);
  engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Sys", &s);
```

Then from QML you can simply `Sys.doYourStuff()`. In your case you need the static function `bool QFile::remove(const QString &fileName)`.

Comment: Thanks, how to find the actual filename on FS from `QUrl` aka `preview`?

Comment: The naming scheme is uniform, so you can just go there and delete the image created on each preview. Investigate how the naming behavior works as files are deleted. You might have to put a counter in your QML code to keep track on which file you should be deleting.